# Function didn't run as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

To start i'm using jquery,php,sql,html & css.

I am facing a issue that is giving me serious problem. I am trying to run a $.post function to retrieve values from my database of a party group(4 members value stored in 4 columns in the database. After retrieving the value, i run a while loop and append each value of the party onto a listview.

Then i send the current while loop value over to another $.post function to check for the rating score for the member i'm currently checking, and retrieve the result to display onto the li that i am currently appending.

This is what i have

```
$('body').on("pagebeforeshow","#p-partyDetail",function(){                  
                var teamID = globalIndex;
                var currentMem = "";

                $.post("retrieveMemDetails.php", 
                {
                    teamID:teamID, // data to pass into php     
                    username:globalUsername,                
                },  // data to pass into php                                                                                    
                    function(response)
                    {
                        var x = 1; // define value as 1

                        while(x<=4){ // if loop is below or equal to 4, run loop                                                            
                            //member = response.mem + x;
                            member = response['mem' + x]; // define member1 in variable, 
                            currentMem = member;
                            console.log("current x value is " + x);

                            if(member !=""){
                                var y = x.toString();
                                console.log("y is " + y);

                                $.post("retrieveRatingDetails.php", 
                                {
                                    username:currentMem, // data to pass into php                                                                           
                                },  // data to pass into php                                                                        
                                    function(response2)
                                    {                                                                                       
                                        $("p#" +y).html(response2.rating);
                                        console.log("full name is " + response2.name + " rating is " + response2.rating);
                                        console.log("retrieve rating valued:"+response2.rating+" to p#"+y);
                                        console.log("end of loop cycle" + y);
                                    }, 'json'
                                );                                                                  

                                $("#partyDetail-listview").append('<li> <img src="images/final-fantasy-7-final-fantasy-vii-6973833-1024-768.jpg"> <h2>'+ member + '</h2> <p id="'+ x +'"></p> </li>').listview("refresh");  
                                console.log("appended count:" + x);
                            }   
                            x++;                            
                        }                               
                    }, 'json'
                );
            });
```

my php for retrieving member detail

```
include_once('db.php');
session_start(); 

$teamID = ($_POST['teamID']);
$username = ($_POST['username']);

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `studentparty` WHERE `id` = '".$teamID."'");
$result3 = $db->query("SELECT *` FROM `userdetails` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $mem1 = $row["mem1"];
        $mem2 = $row["mem2"];
        $mem3 = $row["mem3"];
        $mem4 = $row["mem4"];

        $result2 = json_encode(array("mem1"=>$mem1, "mem2"=>$mem2, "mem3"=>$mem3, "mem4"=>$mem4)); 
            echo $result2;
    }
```

my php for retrieving rating scores

```
include_once('db.php');
session_start(); 

$username = ($_POST['username']);

$result4 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `userdetails` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result4)>0)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4);
        $rating = $row["Rating"];
        $name = $row["FullName"];

        $result5 = json_encode(array("rating"=>$rating, "name"=>$name)); 
            echo $result5;      
    }
```

my member & rating are under different table so i called $.post twice.

Apparently after debugging for hours, i found out that it will loop through

```
console.log("current x value is " + x);
```

then

```
console.log("y is " + y);
```

then

```
console.log("appended count:" + x);
```

running through a total loop count of 4 before it run

```
console.log("full name is " + response2.name + " rating is " + response2.rating);
console.log("retrieve rating valued:"+response2.rating+" to p#"+y);
console.log("end of loop cycle" + y);
```

this caused the rating to only keep updating on the value y, as the flow of the function are already wrong.

My ideal flow is
-retrieve party member details from php
-while displaying mem1 from php using while loop, append a li only my ul.
-send the current mem1 data into my next $.post function to retrieve rating data
-update the li with the rating data
-end of loop and begin with member2

Can someone point out to me what wrong with my script? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you get rating information with detail? By joining them, you don't have to make second post request, which means you don't have to wait for queue(async callbacks) and not push so hard your database to get ratings 4 times instead of just one time.

Comment: because they are under different table
i have a table for party members,
and another table for userDetail, rating is inside this userDetail table.. i can copy and paste over the value of ratings over to party member tables by adding mem1Rating mem2Rating.. so on but i think it will be like playing cheat as rating are more suitable for userDetail

Comment: do you have any idea why it skip through my 2nd $.post request and keep looping until it loop finished then run my 2nd $.post request?

Comment: Because callback functions in jquery are asynch, which means you have to wait until parent's closure ends. So, you will be able to use `response2` after while loop is over. You can set callback funcs as sync, but you need to use $.ajax() and use `async: false`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that one ajax request is enough to get requested data. If you make inner ajax request, you have to wait other lines to be executed. Because it is asynchronous functions. You can also set your ajax call synchronously with the code as in below:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  async: false,
  ...
});
```

But then you have to wait until your callback function is executed. So, sometimes it is dangerous for your performance.

If you change your php side as in below, you will get an array with objects which have member and member's detail.

```
include_once('db.php');
session_start(); 

$teamID = ($_POST['teamID']);

$result_detail = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `studentparty` WHERE `id` = '".$teamID."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result_detail) > 0)
{
  $data = array();
  $mem = array();

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $mem[0] = $row["mem1"];
  $mem[1] = $row["mem2"];
  $mem[2] = $row["mem3"];
  $mem[3] = $row["mem4"];

  for($i = 0; $i < count($mem); $i++) {
    $result_rating = $db->query("SELECT *` FROM `userdetails` WHERE `username` = '".$mem[$i]."'");
    $rating_array = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_rating) > 0)
    {
      $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_rating);
      $rating = $row2["Rating"];
      $name = $row2["FullName"];

      $rating_array = array("rating"=>$rating, "name"=>$name)); 
    }

    $data[$i] = array_merge(array("member" => $mem[$i]), $rating_array);
  }

  $result_json = json_encode($data); 
  echo $result_json;
}
```

I also adopted your javascript code to new response. I couldn't test both. I hope it will work well.

```
$('body').on("pagebeforeshow","#p-partyDetail",function(){                  
  var 
  teamID = globalIndex,
  currentMem = "",
  callback = function(response) {
    var member, id;
    $.each(response, funciton(i, obj) {
      member = obj['member'];
      id = (i+1); // if you have ids for members, you can send in php additionally. it would be better than (i+1) 

      $("#partyDetail-listview").append('<li> <img src="images/final-fantasy-7-final-fantasy-vii-6973833-1024-768.jpg"> <h2>'+ member + '</h2> <p id="'+ id +'"></p> </li>').listview("refresh");  
      console.log("appended count:" + id);

      if (member) {
        $("p#" + id).html(obj['rating']);
        console.log("full name is " + obj['name'] + " rating is " + obj['rating']);
        console.log("retrieve rating valued:"+obj['rating']+" to p#" + id);
        console.log("end of loop cycle" + id);
      }
    });
  };

  $.post("retrieveMemDetails.php", 
  {
    teamID:teamID, // data to pass into php     
    username:globalUsername,                
  },  // data to pass into php                                                                                    
  callback, 'json');
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate I will try it out the code soon and update you. Appreciate your help.